# Is there an ng-repeat reorder drag and drop without jQuery

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

Anyone have some code to reorder a ng-repeat using drag and drop that does not require jQuery? (angularjs dependency only)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've had good results with https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-sortable-view - it's brand new (first commit was last *week*!), but it's extremely easy to work with. You put an `sv-root` attribute on the element (probably a `div`) that's the ancestor of the `ng-repeat` you want to be able to reorder. Then you put an `sv-element` attribute on whichever element you're `ng-repeat`ing, and drag and drop is handled for you.

You can also optionally put an `sv-handle` attribute on some element (probably an image, or a Font Awesome icon) inside your `ng-repeat`, in which case that element gets used as the drag handle. You can also optionally set up "placeholders" (something that shows up as you drag to show where the dragged element will be positioned if you drop it right now) with an `sv-placeholder` attribute on whatever element is your placeholder. And finally, you can optionally specify an `sv-helper` attribute on some element to make that element the one that gets dragged. (So if the thing you want the user to see while dragging needs to be *different* from the thing they see inside the list, that's how you do it).

Oh, and both the `sv-placeholder` and `sv-helper` attributes can go either on elements *outside* the ng-repeat, in which case the same element will be used for every drag situation (use this, for example, if you want a blank gray box as a placeholder the way Trello does it when you drag cards around) -- or those attributes can go on elements *inside* the ng-repeat, in which case you have access to the local scope of that particular ng-repeat element (use this, for example, if you want your placeholder to be "the text of what I'm dragging around, with opacity 50%, and a dashed border around it").

The demos linked from the https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-sortable-view repo demostrate the usage pretty well, so rather than say more about it I'll just let you poke around in the demos. My personal experience so far has been very favorable.

Oh, and it has no dependencies other than Angular. No jQuery or anything else required.

Comment: Brilliant find.  I've been looking for a non-jQuery solution that was easy to implement, and the one you linked works great.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh! Never mind. Works perfectly on touch too. Excellent Work!